# What is a better way to say "the [quality/quantity] is similar for both"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-requests

I don't think this is a correct use of "both". Although it works, like how using a double-negative still gets the message across, I'd like to use an alternative.

Comment: (1) *They have [a] similar quality.* (2) *Their quality is similar.* You can't really use *similar* with *quantity*, since that's objectively countable.

Comment: It might just be more correct to say that the quality or *condition* is similar for *each*, or *each one*. If you are saying any of them out loud you will be understood though you may find a struggle here.

Comment: Change subject from 'the quality' to whatever it is you're writing about.   "The items are of similar quality."